# IGUANA: How to accept file (parse text file) and invoke web service?

Tags: iguana-ui

I am currently using Iguana tool. I know how to parse the `csv/txt` files by adding Source: From Translator and Destination: To translator. The code below has been edited in Destination script.

1. Parse a comma separated CSV file
   local Csv = csv.parseCsv(Data)       -- comma separated (default)
2. Parse a tab separated file
   --local Csv = csv.parseCsv(Data, '\t') -- tab separated (sample message 11)
3. Parse a bar "|" separated file
   --local Csv = csv.parseCsv(Data, '|')  -- bar separated (sample message 12)
   trace(CSV)

I don't know how to invoke web service. Do I need to create a separate channel for invoking web service and parsing a file? If so, how can I run it?